# Error while inserting records from datagridview into sql table by looping

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

whenever i am trying to insert records from datagridview it shows me the below message.
"Index was outside the bounds of the array."

//so how to control looping index. the code is below.

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (@Name, @Name1, @fname,@fname1)", cn)
    Dim InsertCommands() = {"@name", "@name1", "@fname", "@fname1"}
    Dim InsertCommandsIndex As Integer = 0

    For col = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
        For row = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(InsertCommands(InsertCommandsIndex), DataGridView1.Rows(row).Cells(col).Value)
            InsertCommandsIndex += 1
        Next
    Next
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MessageBox.Show("New Record Saved Successfully!", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

End Sub
```

Comment: if the DGV has `AllowUserToAddRows` is true (the default), you are iterating one too many rows probably

Answer (score 0):

```
For col As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
        InsertCommandsIndex = 0
        For row As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(InsertCommands(InsertCommandsIndex), DataGridView1.Rows(row).Cells(col).Value)
            InsertCommandsIndex += 1
        Next
    Next
```